# Running an HTML/JS/CSS only app on Android without external Phonegap/Cordova etc

Tags: javascript, android

Is it possible to run a small and simple game on android using **only CSS/JS/HTML?**

E.g I have built a small game using the all too known 3 folder stucture and I was wondering if there is any easy way to run it on Android tablets without using Phonegap or Cordova.

The scenario I am imagining is this:

- I drop the folder in the tablets filesystem
- I point the browser to that local URL
- then bookmarking it for easier finding.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes, your imagined scenario is 100% feasible. Whether it is "easy" will vary from user to user. Your typical user will probably not enjoy downloading a zip file, unpacking it, then figuring out where the unpacked files exist on the filesystem (which can vary between devices), and then typing in the `file://` address of the application's root directory.

Comment: @apsillers this is for a demonstration for a client of ours - not for general audience use. Therefore I can just instruct our client what to do. It's no problem as long as the our client can easily fire up the app based on our instructions. I will be the one 'installing' the app on the tablets and setting the bookmarks. I am just wondering if it is feasible for mobile browsers to run local index.html files just like a desktop browser would. More specifically I am interested in mobile Chrome browsers

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just give out a URL? ... And if you *really* need to, [use AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: No 3G or Wifi at that place. Didn't know about AppCache, looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer files to your phone right? So why not just transfer the files, fire up your browser and give it a try? On my phone the URL to the Downloads folder looks like file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/. Let us know if it works.

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]

Comment: This is the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also deliver the app from a website. Either just use the files on the website like a typical web app or you can create a manifest file and the browser will cache the files to the local system and will automatically check if the files need to be refreshed.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467724/HTML-Offline-Capabilities-Using-the-Cache-Manifes

Comment: I think this is @svidgen's comment.